# How to create a link-less parent (top level) menu item that doesn't use an anchor <a> tag

Tags: menus, links

My question is closely related to this one: [How make top level menu item not have link, but have sub-menus that are linked?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30303/how-make-top-level-menu-item-not-have-link-but-have-sub-menus-that-are-linked)

When I create menu items with the style customizer, every menu item gets created with an `<a>` tag. When there is a URL present, this will be something like `<a href="URL" class="menu-link">`. When I create a menu item that opens to more menu items, I refer to this as the parent menu item. Sometimes it makes sense to have a page to link to for a parent item, but there are other times when I do not want there to be a link.

The typical, current practice for a link-less menu item seems to be creating a Custom Link item and leaving the URL section blank. This works, but it still creates the menu item using an `<a>` tag, where there is no "href" attribute. This is not really "good" HTML, and it also causes Lighthouse to raise a penalty for an uncrawlable "link".

[image: Example: Creating a Custom Link menu item]
[image: Example: A high level "Custom Link" menu item with a blank URL]

What's the easiest way to solve this problem, of creating a menu item that doesn't use an `<a>` link tag? I'm okay with plugins if they add no overhead when the client loads the page.

Putting `javascript:void(0);` in the URL section is invalid.

Comment: Is `#` not a valid URL if the results of the lighthouse tool are the concern? Note that if you were able to replace the anchor tag with other tags such as a span, you may need to modify stylesheets if they also assume anchor tags. There are also accessibility consequences as a `span` or `div` is not considered an interactive or focusable element, whereas an anchor tag is. Anchor tags are preferable for other reasons too. For example, you can use the keyboard to activate such a tag and open the submenu. Anchors also get picked up as navigation by screen readers and bots, SEO could be impacted

Comment: # is valid, but I don't want the menu item to look like a link if it does nothing.

Since you said this; I checked and the menu only expands on hover, not with the keyboard. So, I'll need to modify the theme or something so that it opens on click or Enter.

Comment: You can fix that with styling though, CSS can even make it look like a checkbox if that's what you really want, looks shouldn't determine the underlying element, semantics and function should.

Comment: While I wouldn't consider this question closed, this above comment is enough for my purposes.